# Best practice: exposing NSManagedObject in framework

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm making a library/framework in iOS that incorporates instant messenger functionalities, using CoreData (plus MagicalRecord and Mogenerator) to store messages and conversations.

I have mainly two `NSManagedObject` classes: `Message` and `Conversation`. For example in `Message` I have some class methods to create entities (say `[Message createMessage]` and some instance methods to query the table (say `[message getLatestMessages]`).

My question is how much can be a good practice to expose publicly in my framework `Message` and `Conversation` (and all their public methods).
Should I take a different approach, like wrapping entities with other classes?
However database context will be always hidden to framework's user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not wrap them, they are already abstracted out enough.  Just expose them as they are just data objects.

You should have one point of entry to retrieve data and to save data.  Some form of DataController that is exposed to the outside application.

Comment: How do you deal the case when either the `NSManagedObject` or its `NSManagedObjectContext` are deallocated ?

Comment: Same way that you handle any other object being deallocated.  If it shouldn't be deallocated then you have a bug.

Comment: I meaned, is there a simple way to get "copy" of NSManagedObject dissociated from the their original context. Let's imagine a function `getObject` that creates a new MOC just for this function (no references on it are kept), executes a query and returns the results. When the MOC will be deallocated, the properties of the returned objects will all equal nil. Is there an idiomatic way to prevent that apart from returning `NSDictionary` or creating specific `NSObject` instances?

Comment: If the object is in the store then any context can retrieve another copy, so you can stand up another context and fetch the object into that context's space. You can also use KVC to get a dictionary copy of the values in the object.  What issue are you trying to solve?  Maybe there is a better approach that I am not seeing from your question.